# MongoDb aggregation framework value of a field where max another field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that has records looking like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("550424ef2f44472856286d56"), "accountId" : "123", 
"contactOperations" :
    [
        { "contactId" : "1", "operation" : 1, "date" : 500 },
        { "contactId" : "1", "operation" : 2, "date" : 501 },
        { "contactId" : "2", "operation" : 1, "date" : 502 } 
    ] 
}
```

I want to know the latest operation number that has been applied on a certain contact.

I'm using the aggregation framework to first unwind the contactOperations and then grouping by accountId and contactOperations.contactId and max contactOperations.date.

```
aggregate([{$unwind : "$contactOperations"}, {$group : {"_id":{"accountId":"$accountId", "contactId":"$contactOperations.contactId"}, "date":{$max:"$contactOperations.date"} }}])
```

The result I get is:

```
"_id" : { "accountId" : "123", "contactId" : "2" }, "time" : 502 }
"_id" : { "accountId" : "123", "contactId" : "1" }, "time" : 501 }
```

Which seems correct so far, but I also need the contactOperations.operation field that was recorded with $max date. How can I select that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to sort the unwind values then apply $last operator to get operation for max date. Hope this query will solve your problem.

```
aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$contactOperations"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "date": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "accountId": "$accountId",
        "contactId": "$contactOperations.contactId"
      },
      "date": {
        $max: "$contactOperations.date"
      },
      "operationId": {
        $last: "$contactOperations.operation"
      }
    }
  }
])
```